# Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'

Tags: mysql

in windows server 2008 i use nodejs to run my js file so to run my js need to have mysql so i installed mysql with command: npm install mysql
after installation there is this log:

```
C:\Users\lol>npm install mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js/1.0.1
mysql@2.0.0-alpha9 node_modules\mysql
├── require-all@0.0.3
└── bignumber.js@1.0.1
```

But evry time i want to run my js i have this error:

```
C:\Users\lol>node D:\node\npauthapi.js

module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\npauthapi.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a global install to avoid this problem:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

you installed it locally in folder `c:\users\lol`, so it's not available in your folder `d:\node`

Comment: Or install it in `D:\node` so it's accessible by `npauthapi.js`

Comment: indeed, that's another solution, but I guess mysql package will be used in more than one project / folder

Comment: pls can you gimme correct command to install mysql in other path ?!

Comment: with command `npm install -g mysql` aslo have same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Place your `.js` file in the same location where you ran the command (`npm install mysql`). This is because after the installation, the MySQL `node_modules` folder will be created in that location so you should place the `.js` file there so that while running, it can get the required modules from the `node_modules` folder.